# Different scroll behaviour in Safari and WKWebview

Tags: javascript, css, swift, safari, wkwebview

why is the horizontal scroll is different when I open this [link](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/07_grid/10_scrollable_grid.html) in wkwebview and safari ?
This is my code so far.

```
func wkwebViewLoad() {
        guard let urlString = NSURL(string: "https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/07_grid/10_scrollable_grid.html") else {return}
        let url =  NSURLRequest(url: urlString as URL)
        // set configuration
        var config: WKWebViewConfiguration?
        let wkContentController = WKUserContentController()
        config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config?.userContentController = wkContentController

        // set wkwebview attributes
        self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), configuration: config!)
        self.view.addSubview(wkWebView!)
        self.wkWebView?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.wkWebView!.load(url as URLRequest)

        // add delegate here
        self.wkWebView?.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.wkWebView?.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.wkWebView?.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
    }
```

In safari, both of the horizontal scroll is working fine.
But in WKWebView, the left grid horizontal scroll is only working when I pan the scrollbar element. When I pan the left grid, it was the right horizontal scrollbar that move instead.

I think WKWebView should have the same behaviour as safari, is it because javascript issue ?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not  under stand, what is the behaviour that you what ?

Comment: edit : I add the expected & current behaviour in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using chartIQ in The project I did not face any issue like this as I have horizontal scrolling in Charts. This may be an issue from the site as they did not handle the response from different media.

If you find any solution to the site you can inject your javascript to WKWebView, check this [link](https://medium.com/@maxcampolo/making-javascript-feel-like-native-ios-with-wkwebview-d92dfefe8d56)